# VBA filepath object syntax

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in VBA in excel:

```
Sub Main()
Dim fd As FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
With fd
    If .Show = -1 Then
            MsgBox "The path is: " & vrtSelectedItem
        Next vrtSelectedItem        Else
    End If
End With

Set fd = myVariable
End Sub
```

What is the context for taking the filepath that the user chose and putting it into the macro?

So if I want to replace the file path of Computer&DelploymentInfo in this code:

```
 .Range("A1:A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[scheduleddate],MATCH([ @HostName],'Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[computername],0))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make the variable Public, outside the scope of a procedure:

```
Public vrtSelectedItem As String

Sub Main()
Dim fd As FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
With fd
    If .Show = -1 Then
            MsgBox "The path is: " & vrtSelectedItem
        Next vrtSelectedItem        Else
    End If
End With

Set fd = myVariable
End Sub
```

---

Or make the procedure a UDF that returns a string argument:

```
Function GetPath() As String
Dim fd As FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
With fd
    If .Show = -1 Then
            MsgBox "The path is: " & vrtSelectedItem
        Next vrtSelectedItem        Else
    End If
End With

GetPath = CStr(vrtSelectedItem)

End Function

Sub Example()
    Dim myFilePath As String

    myFilePath = GetPath & IIf(Right(myFilePath, 1)= "\", vbNullString, "\")
    MsgBox myFilePath
End Sub
```

---

Then finally, you would use:

```
.Range("A1:A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('" & myFilePath & "_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[scheduleddate],MATCH([ @HostName],'" & myFilePath & "_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[computername],0))"
```

Comment: vrtSelectedItem is never assigned a value, may tell the user to use SelectedItems.Item(1)

Comment: @Sorceri I personally don't believe _any_ of the original code will work as it's **full** of syntax errors - but that wasn't what the OP asked :) - I'm just demonstrating the logic required to pass the variable.